# Remix v2 no layout file for index route?

Tags: remix.run

In the documentation for Remix it seems like there are layout files we can use for specific routes.

But I am trying to make a global layout, where I want to put my providers, so I don't have to pass the supabase instance that I create in `root.tsx` to every single provider manually, and use use the Outlet context inside the providers. Thus I want a global layout file.

```js
import { cssBundleHref } from "@remix-run/css-bundle";
import type { LinksFunction, LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
  useLoaderData,
} from "@remix-run/react";
import { createBrowserClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Database } from "@supabase/database.types";

export async function loader({}: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  return {
    env: {
      SUPABASE_URL: process.env.SUPABASE_URL!,
      SUPABASE_ANON_KEY: process.env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
    },
  };
}
export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  ...(cssBundleHref ? [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: cssBundleHref }] : []),
];

export default function App() {
  const { env } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  const [supabase] = useState(() =>
    createBrowserClient<Database>(env.SUPABASE_URL, env.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY)
  );

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet context={{ supabase }} />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I am struggling to actually find anything on google and the remix documentation that is remotely close to this. ChatGPT said something about `app/routes/__layout.tsx` but that does not work seemingly.

Is there actually no root layout file.. Outside the root.tsx file in remix v2?

It would be lovely to just be able to use `const { supabase } = useOutletContext<{ supabase: SupabaseClient<Database>; }>();` inside my providers if I can create a "global layout" that is not `root.tsx`

Comment: Can you share how you have organized your files so it's clear where any layout routes would be structured compared to sub-routes they possibly wrap?